# How to deploy a rabbitmq cluster on minikube using the Bitnami Helm chart?

Tags: rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm, minikube, bitnami

Friends, I am trying to deploy a rabbitmq cluster on Minikube and its not working. What I did so far was this:

```
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
helm install my-release bitnami/rabbitmq
```

When I check the logs of my pod, I get the following results:

```
13:38:04.69 Welcome to the Bitnami rabbitmq container
 13:38:04.69 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-rabbitmq
 13:38:04.70 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-rabbitmq/issues
 13:38:04.70 
 13:38:04.70 INFO  ==> ** Starting RabbitMQ setup **
 13:38:04.71 INFO  ==> Validating settings in RABBITMQ_* env vars..
 13:38:04.71 INFO  ==> Initializing RabbitMQ...
 13:38:04.73 INFO  ==> Starting RabbitMQ in background...
 13:39:53.90 ERROR ==> Couldn't start RabbitMQ in background.
```

And when I describe my pod I see two information which may help to solve the problem:

```
Warning  FailedMount     35m (x3 over 35m)  kubelet  MountVolume.NodeAffinity check failed for volume "pvc-1e09903f-de6a-4fcd-8c3f-490305bb28a6" : error retrieving node: node "minikube" not found.
    
Warning  Unhealthy  9h (x2 over 10h)  kubelet  Readiness probe failed: Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@rabbitmq-0.rabbitmq-headless.default.svc.cluster.local'.
```

Any idea what I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

For installing `RabbitMQ` on `minikube` you can [follow this example](https://github.com/rabbitmq/diy-kubernetes-examples/tree/master/minikube#running-the-example-manually-with-minikube) which is

> an example that demonstrates a RabbitMQ deployment on
> Kubernetes with peer discovery via rabbitmq-peer-discovery-k8s plugin.

It creates 3 replicas of rabbitmq pods using `StatefulSet`.